# What code can I add to my csgo server.cfg to have it only respond to one dns?

Tags: ubuntu, hostname

Im trying to run multiple csgo servers on my server rack and I have diffrent domains that I want to use on each server because the port numbers need to stay the same. Im thinking of finding a line to add to my server.cfg to have host names (like in windows server with IIS were you can set the site to only respond on one url for each site)

Answer (score 1):

CS:GO Does not respond to the dns name but to the IP. then the client is connecting they are not connecting using domain.tld as destination but rather you IP address. The only way you can do this is either having two IP Adresses on the host and binding the SRCDS to each IP or changeing the port number on the SRCDS hosts.